# Hide/remove global search bar in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, customization, eclipse-juno

I recently upgrade Eclipse to Juno and one of the really unwanted (for me) addition is the global search bar - the one in the image with "Quick Access" hint.

[image]

I have to work on a laptop with only a limited screen size (I do a lot of work on the move and can't drag a large monitor with me).  Because of this search bar, the toolbar wraps onto the second line and I loose at least lines of text in the editor.

Of course I can remove a bunch of other buttons and then the bar will fit, but why can't I remove the field that I don't want?

Eclipse sings praises to it as if it were the panacea to all our search problems, but I personally don't use and don't want it.  Has anyone found a way to hide/remove that search bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [Eclipse fullscreen plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/) should take care of that. It removes the top and bottom bars entirely on a key combo. `Ctrl+Alt+Z` is the default.

I am using it to use more real estate on my laptop and wouldnt want to miss it.

I am not aware of a way to get rid only of the search bar while keeping the others in place.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I can't use full screen, as I do have to keep track of a few other things on screen.  I have eclipse full top-bottom of the screen but only about 80% of the screen width to see what's happening in other windows.  Also, if that matters, I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 at present).